# How can I change the underline colour with the transition element in use? (CSS)

Tags: css, colors, css-transitions, transition

On my website, I have used a template to make my navigation bar. My goal is to customise it so that it looks like the BBC navigation bar. (Link:
http://www.bbc.co.uk) Is there any way I can change the border bottom/ underline colour with the transition element in use? And if so, can you please modify the code so that it acts like the BBC menu bar.

Thanks! :D

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Open Sans;  
      }
     
      #cssmenu {
        background: #f96e5b;
        width: auto;
      }
      #cssmenu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        zoom: 1;
      }
      #cssmenu ul:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
        float: right;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-center ul {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: color .25s;
        -moz-transition: color .25s;
        -ms-transition: color .25s;
        -o-transition: color .25s;
        transition: color .25s;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:hover {
        color: #00ff00;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: -3px;
        top: 19px;
        height: 6px;
        width: 6px;
        background: #ffffff;
        opacity: .5;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        background: #333333;
        -webkit-transition: width .25s;
        -moz-transition: width .25s;
        -ms-transition: width .25s;
        -o-transition: width .25s;
        transition: width .25s;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
      #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.active a {
        color: #333333;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
      #cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #cssmenu ul li {
          float: none;
          display: block;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a {
          width: 100%;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
        #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
          border: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a:after {
          display: none;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a:before {
          display: none;
        }
      }
      
      .dateOfPost {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
    </script>
    <title>Ryan Zhang's Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Ryan Zhang's Blog
    </h1>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="aboutMe.html"><span>About Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="tipsNTricks.html"><span>Tips 'n' Tricks</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="inspiration.html"><span>Inspirational Quotes and Words</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="timeline.html"><span>Timeline of Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="dateOfPost">
      Website Goes Live!<br>
      Upload Date:<br>
      25/10/15
    </p>
    <p class="posts">
      Wooh! The website is live now!<br>
      Stick around for:<br>
      Kind Words,<br>
      Interesting Posts,<br>
      Helpful Articles<br>
      And Cool Facts!<br>
      <br>
      -Ryan
    </p>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Navigation Bar Code:

```css
#cssmenu {
        background: #f96e5b;
        width: auto;
      }
      #cssmenu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        zoom: 1;
      }
      #cssmenu ul:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
        float: right;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-center ul {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: color .25s;
        -moz-transition: color .25s;
        -ms-transition: color .25s;
        -o-transition: color .25s;
        transition: color .25s;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:hover {
        color: #00ff00;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: -3px;
        top: 19px;
        height: 6px;
        width: 6px;
        background: #ffffff;
        opacity: .5;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        background: #333333;
        -webkit-transition: width .25s;
        -moz-transition: width .25s;
        -ms-transition: width .25s;
        -o-transition: width .25s;
        transition: width .25s;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
      #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.active a {
        color: #333333;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
      #cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #cssmenu ul li {
          float: none;
          display: block;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a {
          width: 100%;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
        #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
          border: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a:after {
          display: none;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a:before {
          display: none;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give each li its own class.

The easiest was to do this would be to give every li a border-bottom that matches the background color.

Then on hover, just change the border-color property for that specific li.

Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="one">Lorem</li>
  <li class="two">Lorem</li>
  <li class="three">Lorem</li>
  <li class="four">Lorem</li>
  <li class="five">Lorem</li>
  <li class="six">Lorem</li>
</ul> 

li{
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.one:hover{border-color: dodgerblue;}
.two:hover{border-color: seagreen;}
.three:hover{border-color: skyblue;}
.four:hover{border-color: tomato;}
.five:hover{border-color: grey;}
.six:hover{border-color: white;}
```

http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/EVRvjY

Comment: The original bottom border color could be *transparent*. That's the usual method

Comment: @Paulie_D Yep, thats true :) will change

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about applying them the property `border-bottom : Xpx solid #yourColor` ?

I don't really see what you mean otherwise make a screenshot :)